# Covering maps are proper?

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

Under wich conditions a covering map is also proper? For example the covering of the circle is clearly not proper 
Is there anything more general that say, when the cover is a compact space?
Or having finite fibers?

Comment: A covering map is proper iff it's a finite cover. You should try to prove this.

Comment: OK I'm going to do it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a proof of Mike miller suggestion.

Let $\pi: E \to X$ be a covering map and suppose all fibers are finite, let $K$ a compact subset of $X$ and $y_n$ a sequence in the preimage of $K$. The image of this sequence $\pi(y_n) =x_n$is a sequence in a compact so WLOG it converges to $x \in K$. There is some open set $x \in U$ such that $\pi$ induces a homeomorphism of  $\pi^{-1} (U)$ with a finite number of copies $V_1,\dots ,V_m$ of $U$. since $x_n \to x \in U$ WLOG we can assume that $x_n$ is contained in $U$, the sequence $y_n$ is infinite so we can assume it's all contained in $V_1$. The restriction $\pi: V_1 \to U$ is a homeomorphism, hence $y_n$ converges in $V_1 $ iff  $\pi(x_n)$ converges, so $y_n$ converges to some $y \in E$ such that $\pi(y) = x \in K$.

The other direction is obvious.

Edit: this argument works for nets (with small care for finite nets), and a small modification shows that $\pi$ is closed (and have compact fibers), for locally compact Hausdorff spaces that argument is easier.

Comment: You're assuming everything is metric (or at least that compact and sequentially compact are the same). You could give a more general proof without sequences.

Comment: You know that if $p$ is closed, continuous and has compact fibres, then $p$ preserves inverse compactness? It's pretty easy to see that finite fibres on a covering map makes $p$ closed, (and fibres compact) so then you're done. See part of the argument in http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2003&task=show_msg&msg=0122.0001 for more details.

Comment: BTW closed + compact fiber implies proper only in the locally compact world

Comment: But I suppose that my argument works for arbitrary nets so it isn't a problem, the only thing I used was the inifinitenes.

Comment: You show that $p^{-1}[K]$ is compact for compact $K$, which is what follows from closedness and compact fibres

Comment: Any continuous closed map which admits compact fibers is proper. Not only for locally compact spaces.